# How to fetch a PFObject with all it's fields and related objects in one go?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an `NSArray` of `PFObjects` and want to fetch all data related to the objects in this array in one go, so afterwards there is no need to make a new call to parse. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

My answer is assuming the array you want is contained in a PFObject. You can query for this object and use the include key to include the array contained within that key.

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"<object's class name>"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:object.objectId];
    [query includeKey:@"<array key>"];
```

If the objects in your array have pointers to other objects within them you can use the dot syntax to fetch everything at once.

```
   [query includeKey@"<array key>.<pointer in object from array key>"];
```

Run the query once set up and you should retrieve an array of one object since objectIds are unique, within this object will be the array.

```
   [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        if(error){
            // handle error
        }else{
            if([objects count] > 0){

                PFObject *object = objects[0]; // Only one matching object to query
                NSArray *array = object[@"<array key>"]; // Array you want
            }
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PFObject's methods family:

```
+(void)fetchAll:(NSArray*)objects
```

Check out PFObject documentation on those methods https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchAll:

Answer (score 0):

As far I got your query , this might be-

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"CLASS_NAME"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error && objects.count != 0)
     {
         NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", objects);

         for(int i=0; i< objects.count; i--)
         {
             NSDictionary *dict = [objects objectAtIndex:i];
             self.label = [dict objectForKey:@"PROPERTY_KEY"]; //Just example

 /* Also modify this code as per you want to fetch properties of some or all */
 /* Do as you want to with properties and also change key as per need of column/property you want */
         }
     }
 }];
```

This way you will get array and also fetch fetch as you want.